# Dropdown selected value in timer elapsed handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a timer set up on page load in an asp.net webform code-behind. on the ui front are some dropdown lists. When I try getting the selected value of a dropdown in the timer elapsed event, it returns the default value of that dropdown. How can I retrieve the selected value in the timer elapsed event handler? Sorry I have no code to show. AFK at the moment

Comment: what is the interval of the timer which you are using

Comment: @Sujith. The interval is 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the **System.Timers.Timer** is useful for your scenario.

Http is stateless, it won't hold the state.

DropDownList is a **client-side** control , but Timer is a **server-side** control.

The value can't transfer from the client-side to server-side, because you don't have any requests to the server.

How to let the server know the client-side value? **Usually we use GET or POST method**.
But in your situation, I can't see this.

So I think you can try to set the **AutoPostBack** property of the DropDownList to true.

Answer (score 0):

I think

on selectedindexchanged, you should save selected value to session or cookies.
Then you can use it.